# Not a single guide working for Push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform

I tried every guide there + youtube but nothing works 
even when using a custom listener like ( not all the manifest included , too big) :

```
public class MyReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    //code here
} }
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen official [Google developer blog](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)

Clone sample app from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) replace you app id and test, it will work.

Hope this will help !!!

Comment: I want to keep it in parse , if the nonsense continued i will use it . thank you anyway